Add font family to CC Libraries
Can't seem to find a clear answer online on whether its possible to add a typeface family to a saved CC Library? I have a company library with logos and colours but I also want to add the typeface as well I guess so that it could act as a character style so that I essentially could use it to eye dropper that typeface and use that for whatever I'm working on. Is this possible? I use both adobe fonts and custom fonts.

I don't think it is. Adobe fonts is a special thing, subscribe or lose them.. and other non-Adobe fonts can't generally be legally shared, which would be required for libraries. But I could be wrong. I don't really use CC libraries for anything of value.  I won't use some third party (like Adobe) to store valuable business assets.
